# Sprite kit - Moving the node along the x using tochesMoved

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have a Box node and I want move it only left and right by swiping to the left or right.
the problem with the code below is that, as soon as the touch happens the Box jumps to the x position of the touch evidently and then it will move along with your finger.

Not bad but that is not the effect I'm after instead, if the touch happens(no matter where on the screen) the box stays where it is and only move left and right accordingly (- or + value of the x position of the touch) and dose not jump to the position of your finger initially. so the BoxNewPostion.postion.x should not really be equal to touchLocation.x

Just to add that the Box would flicker rapidly if I try

```
CGPoint BoxNewPosition = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x - Box.postion.x, Box.position.y);
```

looks as if it delays on calculating and deducting the x position.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];


        SKSpriteNode* Box = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"BoxNode"];

        CGPoint BoxNewPosition = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, Box.position.y);

        Box.position = BoxNewPosition;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the below code to only move on the x-axis.

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *object1;
    CGPoint destinationLocation;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        [self createObject];
        destinationLocation = CGPointMake(300, 150);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)createObject
{
    object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    object1.position = CGPointMake(300, 150);
    [self addChild:object1];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    destinationLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    destinationLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    float x = fabs(object1.position.x - destinationLocation.x);
    float y = fabs(object1.position.y - destinationLocation.y);

    float divider = 0;
    if(x > y)
    {
        divider = x;
    } else
    {
        divider = y;
    }

    float xMove = (x/divider)*8; // change number to increase or decrease speed
    float yMove = (y/divider)*8; // change number to increase or decrease speed

    if(object1.position.x > destinationLocation.x)
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x-xMove, object1.position.y);

    if(object1.position.x < destinationLocation.x)
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x+xMove, object1.position.y);

    if(object1.position.y > destinationLocation.y)
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x, object1.position.y-yMove);

    if(object1.position.y < destinationLocation.y)
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x, object1.position.y+yMove);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks sangony but the node you have in your code is set to follow the location of the touch which could also be achieved by running an SKAction moveByX:different.x y:0 duration something. what I need is to touch anywhere on the screen and go left by eg. +10x the box does the same in real time respective to its original position.

Comment: @adimona - Maybe I do not understand your question then. The code I posted moves the sprite smoothly to the touch location, from start to finish, and changes its path in the midstream if the touch location changes. You cannot do that with SKAction move because the action will continue to its originally set destination unless you cancel action and start a new one. If I understood your first comment correctly, you said that your object "jumped" to the first touch location and then smoothly tracked afterwards. My code tracks smoothly from beginning to end.